# How to upload multiple files via Sinatra and avoid NoMethodError - undefined method `read' for "#<File:0x0000000xxxxxx0>":String

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to upload the nth file from a multi-file array:

```
post '/upload2' do
  puts params
  #pp params
  mx=params['images'].map{|f| f[:filename] }.join(";")
  filename=mx.split(';')[0] 
  puts filename 
  mz= params['images'].map{|f| f[:tempfile] }.join(";")
  file=mz.split(';')[0]
  puts file

  path = "/home/user/Descargas/sinatra_ajax-master/#{filename}"

  File.open(path, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(file.read)
  end
  erb :index

end
```

My HTML is:

```
<form action="/upload2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

But my code fails and I don't know why.

Comment: why is this question being downvoted with no explanation? it's not perfect, but there's definitely enough substance to get good answers going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `join()` on your tempfiles:

```
mz= params['images'].map{|f| f[:tempfile] }.join(";")
```

You're taking a a bunch of `File` objects and forcing them into strings using `to_s()`. But the default `to_s` for a `File` is to create this generally useless thing:

```
"#<File:0x0000000xxxxxx0>"
```

Which is why you're getting the error message that you are.

---

As for how to fix it, the solution is simply to not turn your files into strings. I don't entirely understand why you're taking an array, joining it into a string, then immediately splitting the string back into an array. I would just not do any of that:

```
post '/upload2' do
  puts params

  filename = params["images"][0][:filename]
  puts filename

  tempfile = params["images"][0][:tempfile]
  puts tempfile

  path = "/home/user/Descargas/sinatra_ajax-master/#{filename}"

    File.open(path, 'wb') do |f|
      f.write(tempfile.read)
    end

  erb :index

end
```

Comment: HI very thankyou for your help ; this help me so much :)

Comment: really not works very well ; but you help me to solve this  ; thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution thanks to all

UPDATE

---

This code serves to upload multiple rows but the question was only part of the code

THIS is the first code

```
 post '/upload2' do
      puts params
      #pp params



    @filename = params[:images][0][:filename]
    file = params[:images][0][:tempfile]

    File.open("/home/user/Descargas/sinatra_ajax-master/#{@filename}", 'wb') do |f|
     f.write(file.read)
    end





      erb :index

    end
```

this is the full code

```
post '/upload2' do
    puts params['images'].map{|f| f[:filename] }.join(";")
    k=params['images'].map{|f| f[:filename] }.join(";")
    $param=k.chomp.split(";")
    array_length= $param.length   #or $param.size
    array_lengthx = array_length - 1
    puts "legth of $param is : #{array_length}"



    i = 0
    i=i-1
    puts array_lengthx
    puts i
    while i.to_i < array_lengthx do
    i =i+1
    puts i
    @filename = params[:images][i][:filename]
    file = params[:images][i][:tempfile]
    path="/home/user/Descargas/sinatra_ajax-master/#{@filename}"
    File.open("/home/user/Descargas/sinatra_ajax-master/#{@filename}", 'wb') do |f|
     f.write(file.read)
    end

    end

end
```

this is html code

```html
<form action="/upload2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Explain why this is an appropriate, usable solution. If the final code has something unique about it that others can benefit from it then it's helpful to post, otherwise don't because it confuses others about what the appropriate answer really is. Remember, SO isn't a discussion list, it's like an online encyclopedia of programming problems and their solutions. "thanks eiko" isn't appropriate in an answer either.

Comment: yes I trying to improve the answer I will put best answer later

Comment: I put better explain now